# Ubuntu 14.04 on yoga 2 pro

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am using a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro with an i7 processor. The Ubuntu download says that it's for AMD64. Will Ubuntu 14.04 work on my device?

Comment: AMD64 stands for 64Bit.

Comment: Is your device using 64 bit or 32 bit?? Find that out and decide which to install from ubuntu download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the AMD64 ISO of Ubuntu 14.04 will work, since your computer's processor is 64bit.

Comment: @thatguy - No problem! To accept an answer on this site, hit the checkmark to the left of the relevant answer.